# Spark 2.2.0 intermittently produces `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo` error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I'm running a Spark application in cluster mode via spark-submit, and I have a custom Kryo registrator. The JAR is built with `sbt "+assembly"`. Occasionally, after letting the job run for a while, some of the executors will produce errors like the below during a `treeAggregate` operation. What's weird is that the error only happens occasionally, after many, many objects have already been successfully serialized by Kryo. Often the entire Spark job finishes without apparent issue. When this error does pop up, it's usually accompanied by the task seeming to hang, and I need to kill Spark manually.

```
17/08/29 22:39:04 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error opening block StreamChunkId{streamId=542074019336, chunkIndex=0} for request from /10.0.29.65:34332
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newInstance(KryoSerializer.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.dataSerializeStream(SerializerManager.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$dropFromMemory$3.apply(BlockManager.scala:1382)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$dropFromMemory$3.apply(BlockManager.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.put(DiskStore.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.dropFromMemory(BlockManager.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.org$apache$spark$storage$memory$MemoryStore$$dropBlock$1(MemoryStore.scala:524)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore$$anonfun$evictBlocksToFreeSpace$2.apply(MemoryStore.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore$$anonfun$evictBlocksToFreeSpace$2.apply(MemoryStore.scala:539)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.evictBlocksToFreeSpace(MemoryStore.scala:539)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.StorageMemoryPool.acquireMemory(StorageMemoryPool.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.StorageMemoryPool.acquireMemory(StorageMemoryPool.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.StaticMemoryManager.acquireStorageMemory(StaticMemoryManager.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putBytes(MemoryStore.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.maybeCacheDiskBytesInMemory(BlockManager.scala:1143)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doGetLocalBytes(BlockManager.scala:594)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$getLocalBytes$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:559)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$getLocalBytes$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:559)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocalBytes(BlockManager.scala:559)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getBlockData(BlockManager.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.OneForOneStreamManager.getChunk(OneForOneStreamManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processFetchRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.bar.MyKryoRegistrator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anonfun$newKryo$5.apply(KryoSerializer.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anonfun$newKryo$5.apply(KryoSerializer.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:134)
    ... 60 more
```

My Spark session looks like this:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("FooBar")
                .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
                .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2047m")                                        
                .config("spark.kryo.registrator","com.foo.bar.MyKryoRegistrator")
                .config("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
                .config("spark.network.timeout", "3600s")
                .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
                .config("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
                .config("spark.shuffle.spill", "true")
                .getOrCreate()
```

and I'm passing these configuration options to spark-submit:

```
--conf "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=400s"
--conf "spark.speculation=true"
--conf "spark.speculation.multiplier=30"
--conf "spark.speculation.quantile=0.95"
--conf "spark.memory.useLegacyMode=true"
--conf "spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.8"
--conf "spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.2"
--driver-java-options "-XX:+UseG1GC"
```

This is what my registrator code looks like:

```
package com.foo.bar

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoRegistrator

class MyKryoRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
    kryo.register(classOf[Array[Array[Byte]]])
    kryo.register(classOf[Array[Double]])
    kryo.register(classOf[Array[Int]])
    kryo.register(classOf[Array[Object]])
    kryo.register(classOf[Array[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive]])
    kryo.register(classOf[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.ofRef[_]])
    kryo.register(Class.forName("scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1"))
    kryo.register(classOf[scala.util.matching.Regex])

    kryo.register(classOf[java.lang.Class[_]])
    kryo.register(classOf[java.util.Date])

    kryo.register(classOf[awscala.s3.Bucket])
    kryo.register(classOf[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Owner])

    kryo.register(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast"))

    kryo.register(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Instance"))
    kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector])
    kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector])
    kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector])
    kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer])
    kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow])
    kryo.register(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedBatch"))
    kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.storage.BroadcastBlockId])
  }
}
```

I found some discussion of what sounds like a very similar issue ([KryoSerializer cannot find my SparkKryoRegistrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064751/kryoserializer-cannot-find-my-sparkkryoregistrator)), but there's unfortunately no answer.

Any idea what the issue might be? Is this a bug in Spark?

Comment: Any reason for explicitly setting: `config("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")`? Are you doing some custom registration yourself?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, I'm registering several classes that aren't registered by default. I've added my registrator code to the end of the post.

Comment: I added some more logging to Spark's Kryo serialization code. It seems that when this error happens, Spark is using the sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader ClassLoader instead of the usual org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader. MutableURLClassLoader can see my custom Kryo registrator, but the AppClassLoader can't. Why this would happen, I don't know.

Comment: I was able to find a workaround. I simply copied my Spark application's JAR to the driver and worker machines, and passed the following Spark config options to `spark-submit`: `--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/path/to/sparklogisticregre‌​ssion.jar" --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/path/to/sparklogisticreg‌​ression.jar"`.

This doesn't answer my question (why does this happen and is it a bug?), so I'll refrain from making this the answer to my own question for now. I've also reported this behavior and potential bug at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21928.